# Print array elements from index k

Tags: bash

I have a bash array and want to print the array elements starting from index `k`.

Things did not work out with the following strategy.

```
printf "%s\n" "${ar[$j:]}"
```

Comment: Why not just use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `${ar[@]:j}`<sup>1</sup>. From the `Parameter Expansion` section of `man bash`:

```
   ${parameter:offset:length}
   .
   .
   .
          If parameter is an indexed array name subscripted by @ or *, the
          result is the length members of the array beginning  with  ${pa‐
          rameter[offset]}.   A  negative  offset is taken relative to one
          greater than the maximum index of the specified array.  It is an
          expansion error if length evaluates to a number less than zero.
```

So given

```
$ ar=("1" "2 3" "4" "5 6" "7 8" "9")
```

then (remembering that bash array indixing is 0-based):

```
$ j=3; printf '%s\n' "${ar[@]:j}"
5 6
7 8
9
```

---

Alternatively, use a C-style for loop:

```
for ((i=k;i<${#ar[@]};i++)); do
  printf '%s\n' "${ar[i]}"
done
```

---

1. or `${ar[@]:$j}` if you prefer - the second `$` is optional, since the indices are evaluated in a numerical context similar to `((...))`